# c# winform to inspect an object during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to display the public Property/Values of an arbitrary object during runtime in a GUI.

Is there a winform which allows the user to view the content of any object like in debug mode? The object will hold many Dictionaries >  and it would be nice to be able to expand and view the contents of those lists during runtime.

If not available, is there someway to achieve something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Use the `PropertyGrid` control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `PropertyGrid`:

```
var form = new Form();

form.Controls.Add
 (
   new PropertyGrid() 
   { 
     SelectedObject = new { A = "Hi", B = new [] { 32, 40 } } 
   }
 );

form.Show();
```

It's quite far from how the debugger one works, but it can be quite easily modified to handle any special cases you might have.

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is create a form with a PropertyGrid on it. Then set the selected object.

[image]

```
using xxx.CFM.UI.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace xxx.CFM.UI.Forms
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Form used to inspect objects at runtime
    /// </summary>
    public partial class frmInspector : BaseForm
    {
        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the 
        /// </summary>
        public object SelectedObject
        {
            get { return propertyGrid.SelectedObject; }
            set { propertyGrid.SelectedObject = value; }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public frmInspector(object objectToInspect)
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                this.SelectedObject = objectToInspect;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                UIMessage.DisplayError(ex);
            }
        }

        #endregion Constructor

        #region Events

        /// <summary>
        /// Closes the form
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object</param>
        /// <param name="e">args</param>
        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                UIMessage.DisplayError(ex);
            }
        }

        #endregion Events
    }
}
```

I use this on a context menu in a grid for example to expect the data record below it:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Opens the object inspector
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object</param>
    /// <param name="e">args</param>
    private void inspectorMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Get the payload
            SectionDataTreeListMenuItemPayload payload = (sender as ToolStripMenuItem).Tag as SectionDataTreeListMenuItemPayload;

            if (payload == null || payload.DataRow == null)
                return;

            using (frmInspector frmInspector = new frmInspector(payload.DataRow))
                frmInspector.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UIMessage.DisplayError(ex);
        }
    }
```

another little trick you can do is to ensure the form is only available when built in debug mode by using the below code using a 'compiler directive'. (if you want it only used for debugging of course)

```
#if DEBUG

                //Add object inspector menu item if built in debug mode
                ToolStripMenuItem inspectorMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
                inspectorMenuItem.Text = "Inspect Object";
                inspectorMenuItem.Image = Properties.Resources.Inspect24x24;
                inspectorMenuItem.Click += inspectorMenuItem_Click;
                inspectorMenuItem.Tag = payload;
                contextMenuStrip.Items.Add(inspectorMenuItem);

#endif
```